# Google reCaptcha not loading in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, recaptcha, mobile-devices

Google recaptcha is not showing up in the mobiles devices

Not sure if it is due to the https url!

Comment: Could you find a solution to this. If so please share. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Did you verified the [browser requirements](https://support.google.com/recaptcha/#6223828) in the docs?